# Multiple Angular2 router outlets

Tags: angular2-routing

I have setup 2 router outlets(two different divs on the screen that load different stuff). I am able to open pages in  but not the other router outlet, so I guess Im missing something.

app.routes.ts

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: 'component1', component: component1},
    { path: 'component2', component: component2, outlet: 'router2'},
];
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="router2"></router-outlet>
```

routing to component2

```
<button routerLink="/event-gallery">go</button>
```

Comment: Error I get when clicking on a button is "Error: Cannot match any routes.".

Comment: I think routerLink format is wrong